# How to make client sleep in the function?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a thread pool on the function that the clients calling.. to make only (n) clients execute this function `upload()` and the others wait.. i tried to call `sleep()` in the implementation of the function but it didn't work ... 
note: I'm doing this to have time to see that other clients doesn't execute the function while there are (n) clients execute it...

i need fast help please ..

the code of Server:

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ExcutorInterface
{
public Server()throws RemoteException
{
    System.out.println("Server is in listening mode");
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException
{
    try{
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1234);
    Server p=new Server();
    Naming.bind("//127.0.0.1:1234/obj",p);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred : "+e.getMessage());
    }     
}
@Override
public void executeJob()  throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Inside executeJob...");
    doJob a=new doJob("req_id","usrname","pwd");
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    threadExecutor.execute(a);
    threadExecutor.shutdown(); 
}
```

}

the code of doJob :

```
public class doJob implements Runnable {
String request_id="", usrnamee="", pswd="";
public static int i = 1;

public doJob(String request_id,String usrnamee,String pswd) {
    this.request_id=request_id;
    this.usrnamee=usrnamee;
    this.pswd=pswd;
}
public void upload() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
     Thread.sleep(1000*15);
  }
 public void run() {
            upload();
  }
```

}

and I call    `executeJob();` in the client

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - use the `Executor`'s from `java.concurrent`.

Comment: Instead of creating a new ExecutorService every time, use the same ExecutorService by moving it to a non-static field of your Server class, and do not call shutdown() on it.

Comment: @Hala El Barchah, Anders' suggestion is a good one. Also, you should be aware that Thread.sleep() doesn't guarantee that the thread will sleep for the requested time. You need to surround it in a try/catch, catching InterruptedException and checking how long the thread slept. Loop until the thread sleeps the required length of time.

Comment: @VGR, did you mean move it to a static field?

Comment: I write  System.out.println("inside upload"); in the function upload()
  and it doesn't write any thing ... so the function doesn't execute!!!
any body knows why plz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to make "threadExecutor" a static member variable of 
server.
If you want only n clients then make the pool have n threads
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);

Shutting down within execute method id does not seem right.

The pool should be shutdown only when you decide to shutdown the 
server.

Till then it should be alive and process the client requests.
So you have to remove the shutdown and newFixedThreadPool statements
out of the executeJob method.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, you should surround the Thread.sleep in a try/catch and make sure the thread sleeps as long as you wish it to do so. It would look something like this:

```
long wakeTime = new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 15);
while ((new Date()).getTime() < wakeTime) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000*15);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

I suspect your thread was waking early because of a signal perhaps because of your call to threadExecutor.shutdown() immediately after threadExecutor.execute(a). You might want to consider calling threadExecutor.awaitTermination() as well.

Edits after learning that the task never executes:

Because threadExecutor.shutdown() doesn't wait for the tasks to complete, it looks like your program is immediately exiting. You should try using threadExecutor.awaitTermination() after your call to threadExecutor.shutdown(), placing it in a loop similar to the one suggested for Thread.sleep().

Comment: One other ancillary suggestion is that you use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit to convert time periods. So, for instance, you could use TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15).

Comment: It works at this way ... thanks alot :)
@pens-fan-69

Comment: No problem, @HalaElBarchah. I would appreciate it if you accepted this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the thread pool and use a counting semaphore to control inline execution of the upload.

Answer (score -1):

I hope Thread.sleep() will help you to resolve.
Also you can use wait().

Comment: Thread.sleep() doen't work... the client hits upload() and stops immediatly

Comment: @HalaElBarchah That's what will happen in any implementation. It is the behaviour you specified: 'the others wait'. Your objection is incomprehensible.